# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe2'

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, pre-trained-model, caffe2

I have successfully installed pytorch from source using command `git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git`  on my Windows 11 with CPU. But I cannot run the pretrained DL model. It gives error on line:  `from caffe2.python import workspace`. Even though I have workspace on `pytorch/caffe2/python/workspace`. Please guide if there is anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please enable BUILD_CAFFE2 while building PyTorch from source if not already done.

Comment: I've already built pytorch from source. How can I enable BUILD_CAFFE2 at this point??